# Ant: Fetch multiple file names from xmlproperty, create custom URL for each and download them?

Tags: ant

I want to write an ANT script which does the following:

1. Downloads a XML file which contains file names
2. For each file name from step 1: Construct a URL (string) consisting of a base URL and the file name
3. Download each file using a Get task

Task 1 is easy with the task xmlproperty. But I can't find a way to construct a URL of these file names an download each of them.

Here is my script:

```
<project name="Project ABC" default="download">
    <property name="workspace" value="ant-workspace"/>
    <property name="jenkinsBaseUrl" value="http://jenkins/project_abc"/>
    <property name="jenkinsXmlApi" value="${jenkinsBaseUrl}/api/xml"/>

    <target name="prepare-download">
        <mkdir dir="${workspace}"/>
        <get src="${jenkinsXmlApi}" dest="${workspace}/jenkins.xml"/>
        <xmlproperty file="${workspace}/jenkins.xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="download" depends="prepare-download">
        <echo message="${mavenBuild.artifact.fileName}"/>
        <!-- [echo] project_a-internet.zip,project_a-libs-forbidden.zip,project_a-libs-lgpl.zip -->

        <get dest="${workspace}">
            <propertyresource name="${jenkinsBaseUrl}/${mavenBuild.artifact.fileName}" />
        </get>
    </target>
</project>
```

Then run: ant download

Any ideas?

Comment: The main problem here is that `xmlproperty` will always group property values into a comma delimited list if they share the same set of parent elements, which is not very useful because Ant doesn't natively have a way to execute code loops over lists of items. You could try using Ant-contrib, which is a set of extra Ant tasks, one of which being `<for>`. Alternatively, you might want to check out the 3rd party `xmltask` which is capable of performing advanced operations on XML input. http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/

Comment: @CAustin Thanks, for your explaination, I wasn't aware of these options, I'll try them out :)